# How to read xml into mysql db

Tags: php, arrays, xml, parsing, object

I am pulling data from an external site using simplexml_load_file and need to dump into my local database.  I do not know how to parse the data so that I can perform my sql insert.  Please tell me how to grab the column headings and values from the simplexml_load_file results. Because I may not always know the heading names, Ideally I would like to pull the heading and value in as variables and load them both into sql as values to two columns; column_nam and column_value. Below is an example of the data usnig the print_r

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [sessionid] => p_panda143ccfcf692ede95e|43413dc74e459ecb|41b5f89600000000|41c18afc4b000000|
        )

```
[OBJECT] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [name] => clinicalreport
                [op] => search_filedelivery
            )

        [reports_viewed] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [reports_delivered] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [clinicalreport] => 3006163008
        [orders_transmitted] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [report_request_date] => 10/7/2014  9:17 AM
        [reports_undelivered] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [person_middle_name] => R
        [reports_printed] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [creation_date] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [ownerid] => 3003154010
        [reports_count] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [sponsor_name] => LabCorp Birmingham
        [receivingorganization] => 3003154010
        [organization_name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [sponsor] => 1502182
        [document] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [clearance] => 10
        [report_subject] => HL7 Order Copy
        [report_service_date] => 10/7/2014  9:19 AM
        [reports_forwarded] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [forwarded] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [std_orders_created] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [person_last_name] => Angles
        [is_viewed] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [is_latest] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [is_abnormal] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [expiration_date] => 4/5/2015  9:19 AM
        [sequence] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [is_annotated] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [originalreport] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [person_account_number] => 1799
        [filler_order_number] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [placer_order_number] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [is_forwarded] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [report_priority] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [person] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [receiving_cg_fname] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [creation_datetime] => 10/7/2014  9:19 AM
        [receiving_cg_lname] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [is_downloaded] => N
        [receiving_cg_mname] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [report_status] => NA
        [lab_code] => MB
        [ordering_cg_suffix] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [ordering_cg_fname] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [ordering_client_id] => 8001631
        [person_first_name] => Madeleine
        [report_type] => ORDER
        [ordering_cg_lname] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [ordering_cg_mname] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [previousreport] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [orderresult] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [receiving_cg_suffix] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [psc_orders_created] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [receiving_client_id] => 8001631
        [is_printed] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [content_expiration_date] => 2/4/2015  9:19 AM
        [person_suffix] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

        [abnormals_count] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
            )

    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  But first why is there a '-1' by my question.

SOLUTION - I needed to send the results of the simplexml_load_file in the new function  xml2array. this function provided me with each name and value.

```
$myXML = simplexml_load_file($url);

function xml2array($myXML) {
  $arr = array();
  foreach ($myXML as $element) {
    $tag = $element->getName();   
    $e = get_object_vars($element);
    if (!empty($e)) {
      $arr[$tag] = $element instanceof SimpleXMLElement ? xml2array($element) : $e;
    }
    else {
      $arr[$tag] = trim($element);
    } 
  }
  return $arr;
}
```

I found the function here
http://bookofzeus.com/articles/convert-simplexml-object-into-php-array/